# Phonegap with Facebook and Twitter Integration

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, twitter

I have developed an app using Phonegap for Android and iOS.It has an **Index.html**.From a link on this page I navigate to another html page **"Share.html"**.From this html page i click a buton to show an actionsheet with two options :1. Facebook, 2.Twitter.

When I click any of these two options, I set **data-ajax= false** for a full page refresh. On both pages **"facebook.html"** and **"twitter.html"** I add a header and anchor tag with **data-rel="back"**.

Now my problem is on clicking them I get back in **"Share.html"** but all the css is gone for the page. And there is no back button that I added to this page previously with **add-data-back-btn= "true"**.

I want to go back to "Share.html" page on click of any button and the css used before should be applied.All pages should wok as they worked before. How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing ajax navigations? If so, try using:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "yourPage.html", { transition: "none"} );
```